# Handle receive values from server in multi clients with same IP

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I want to connect to server with multiple clients and some clients in the same computer and same IP address. I mean, in my application, in the different forms, user can connect to server and get value from server in the same time. I read more about multi clients but all of them was about multi clients in different computer or different applications. I think, i handle received values from server in client side with a dictionary that save connected clients and every received value set in a queue, and if not run any received value then get a data from queue and etc. but i don't know how can i know this received values is for which request from client. 
I try solve this problem around 3 days and i couldn't. Please if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

For sure it's better to specify your Platform, Environment and ... when you have a question about it, Well in general cases there's no different. BTW, I assume it's .Net.

### **.Net platform**

If you do socket programming and you wanna recognize different requests from multiple clients in same Computer/IP the `Client.RemoteEndPoint` from `TcpClient` class give you that. Actually, it's consists of IP:Port and It's a key to get you know how it works separately, which in each programming languages with high probability it would be like that because in the same computer each endpoint needs to have same IP but different port. So even in the same computer you would have this as an ID (IP:Port) and can use it as the key within your dictionary.

### **General cases**

In some general ways for each platform or without usages of built-in frameworks you could consider your server like a WebServer (I see It's more complex) but how a WebServer would process each request by itself even if they are 2 different sessions in 2 browsers from 1 computer and 1 port? So you should implement your code in that way. Actually, you should put some extra information on each request and give them some unique pieces of information (ID) on your own. Then you could identify them from each other.